# My AJAX call is working fine, but the success function is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax
({
    url: 'includes/updateelected.php',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'POST',

    success:function(edit) {
        if(edit=="success")
        {
           swal({
                title: "SUCCESS:",
                text: "Elected Official Updated Successfully!",
                icon: "success",
                timer: 2000,
                button: false
            })

            $('#data-table-command').bootgrid('reload'); // Refresh bootgrid datatable.
            $('#editUser')[0].reset();


        }
    },

    error:function(edit)
    {
        swal('ERROR:','Please try again or call your Systems Administrator','error');
    }
});
```

My AJAX code is working, the database gets updated but the success function is not firing. Any idea why? success:function(edit) { doesn't seem to be executing. updateelected.php is echoing "success" on the last line.
My updateelected.php file:

```
<?php 
include "db.php";    

$electedId  = escape($_POST['electedId']);
$membername = escape($_POST['membername']);
$party      = escape($_POST['party']);
$district   = escape($_POST['district']);
$position   = escape($_POST['position']);
$room       = escape($_POST['room']);
$phone      = escape($_POST['phone']);
$email      = escape($_POST['email']);
$chamber    = escape($_POST['chamber']);
$legAssist  = escape($_POST['legAssist']);
$laEmail    = escape($_POST['laEmail']);
$supports   = escape($_POST['supports']);

$file  = $_FILES['electedfile']['name'];
$file  = strtolower($file);
$file_temp = $_FILES['electedfile']['tmp_name'];

if($file) {

    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, "/electionhope/electedimages/$file");


} else {

    $file = $_POST['preview'];
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file);
    $file = $path_parts['basename'];
        
}

$sql = "UPDATE elected SET membername = '$membername', party = '$party', district = '$district', position = '$position', room = '$room', phone = '$phone', email = '$email', chamber = '$chamber', legAssist = '$legAssist', laEmail = '$laEmail', supports = '$supports', image = '$file' WHERE electedId = $electedId";
query($sql);

echo "success";
```

?>

As you can see echo "success"; is right after the $sql update which works fine.

Comment: What about `error:function`? and check your console to see if there is an error

Comment: Also try to use complete and see what happen? `complete: function(jqXHR) {if(jqXHR.readyState === 4) ....`

Comment: There is no error in the console.

Comment: I am not familiar with how to use complete: function(jqXHR)

Comment: instead of success use complete like this: `complete: function(jqXHR) { /* print jqXHR.readyState*/}` and tell me the value of `readyState`

Comment: do `console.log(edit)`. i think "success" is not the only string you will find there, because you say "...echoing 'success' on the last line." are there other lines before that?

Comment: go to developer tools and check what exactly your XHR request returns, probably some PHP warnings or other stuff; or do `success:function(edit) { console.log(edit) }`

Comment: I added error_reporting(0); to that one file and everything is working fine now.

Comment: Good solution to ignore errors.....

Comment: it wasn't the solution it just made it work so I could test my code.  I have since resolved all the errors.  I still had to make PHP shut the hell up and stop reporting warnings.  But I can deal with those.